What information is `synapse.ml.fabric.telemetry_utils.report_usage_telemetry` sending?
When I import SemPy I get the following messages:
>>> import sempy
log_telemetry: sempy.relationships
log_telemetry: sempy.dependencies
log_telemetry: sempy.fabric
log_telemetry: sempy

I am trying to understand what information SemPy's telemetry utilities are sending. In sempy.__init__.py I found the following lines:
...
from ._utils._telemetry import log_telemetry
...
# log telemetry
log_telemetry(activity_name="sempy")
...

I found the source file for the above import: /site-packages/sempy/_utils/_telemetry.py.
import os

from .. import _version

try:
    from synapse.ml.fabric.telemetry_utils import report_usage_telemetry
    REPORT_USAGE_TELEMETRY_ENV = "REPORT_USAGE_TELEMETRY" # Environment variable to control telemetry reporting
except ImportError:
    report_usage_telemetry = None

def log_telemetry(activity_name: str = ""):
    if report_usage_telemetry and \
            os.environ.get(REPORT_USAGE_TELEMETRY_ENV, "true").lower() == "true":
        report_usage_telemetry(
            "PyLibraryImport",
            activity_name,
            attributes={"version": _version.get_versions()['version'], "ImportType": "EXPLICIT_IMPORTED_BY_USER"},
       )
    else:
        # For unit test and robustness
        print(f"log_telemetry: {activity_name}")

Google search for only gives this, which doesn't appear to be the same package. But similarly, "synapse.ml.fabric.telemetry_utils" does not show anything else either. Not event the search "synapse" and "telemetry_utils" showed anything else.
How am I able to learn and validate what information is actually being sent?
